# How do I make my object conform to a protocol?

Tags: ios, swift

```
protocol LiveCellProtocol: class{
    var identifier: Int { get set }
}
public class CoreCellObject: NSObject, LiveCellProtocol {
    var identifier: String = "" //will be set during init.
    init() {
        self.identifier = NSStringFromClass(self.dynamicType) + ":" + NSUUID().UUIDString
    }
}
```

The error is that it does not conform to the protocol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your protocol defines a property named 'identifier' as an Int but youve implemented it as a String in your class. It has to be of the same type as defined in your protocol, thats why it doesn't conform

Comment: Thanks. Duh, simple mistake.